# JSF + Wildfly connect in many databases dynamically

Tags: jboss, wildfly, multi-tenant

I have a Web Application using JSF + CDI + JPA and the Wildfly server. until this moment Wildfly are managing the transactions, auth security, email service... So my problem is that I need my system to access multiples databases. So that the client are logging in, he put their login and password and also select the database.

I already Googled a lot and solutions as multi-tenancy did not seem very interesting. I also thought of taking this responsibility of the server, making the connection in the application and still managing to use the injections usually, but I have a lot of troubles with it, like on security management and in all of things that Wildfly managed before.

Some tips or ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: JTA transactions can span across multiple resources (thus, databases).

Comment: I'm using JTA transactions, but I can't figure out how I can do it without creating a Persistence Unit  for each database. In my case, each client organization will have a database. And I don't want to generate a .war file every time that I have a new client... (All databases are the same structure)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Hibernate multitenancy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy) with `DATABASE` mode. This works quite nicely in WildFly 10.

Basically, you just need to implement a `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` which provides a connection to the appropriate database for the current request.

This should solve your problem at the database level. You still need to figure out how to determine the correct database for the current request, e.g. deriving it from the URI of the current HTTP request and storing it in a `@RequestScoped` bean.